# In matlab, I got different values in a method of class and out

Tags: matlab

In the matlab, I defined a class and instantiated the class in another script, but I got different values in and out of the method. My matlab code are shown bellow:

**test_add.m**

```
classdef test_add
    properties
        a
        b
    end
    methods
        function obj = test_add(a, b)
            obj.a = a;
            obj.b = b;
        end
        function c = add_1(obj)
            c = obj.a + 1;
        end
        function inter(obj, t)
            for i = 1:t
                obj.a = obj.add_1();
            end
            fprintf('In the method:\n');
            fprintf('a = %d\n',obj.a);
            fprintf('b = %d\n',obj.b);
            disp('=======================');
        end
    end
end
```

**main.m**

```
tt = test_add(1,2);
tt.inter(3);
fprintf('Out of the method:\n');
fprintf('a = %d\n',tt.a);
fprintf('b = %d\n',tt.b);
```

**output:**

```
In the method:
a = 4
b = 2
=======================
Out of the method:
a = 1
b = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab there are two type of classes: handle class and Value class. If you said nothing you get the **Value** class. Most of the OO languages out there are using handle class semantic.

So, you have two options:

1. Change you class to handle class by inheriting from handle

   ```
   classdef test_add < handle
   ```
2. Stay with Value class and change your inter function to return obj.

   But then, in main call obj=tt.inter(3) to get the updated object.

   ```
    function obj = inter(obj, t)
               for i = 1:t
                   obj.a = obj.add_1();
               end
               fprintf('In the method:\n');
               fprintf('a = %d\n',obj.a);
               fprintf('b = %d\n',obj.b);
               disp('=======================');
           end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of value class vs handle class, the solution is:

**test_add.m**

```
classdef test_add < handle
    ...
end
```

Then, the output is:

```
In the method:
a = 4
b = 2
=======================
Out of the method:
a = 4
b = 2
```